# Sort the item inside a menu (A-z)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a custom menu in angular.

I want to sort it in alphabetical order. I have static and dynamic items in it. How can I sort this?

Below is the HTML code.

```html
 <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in dropdown-custom-width-links"
      aria-labelledby="appsDropdown" id="appsDropdownPopup">
      <h6 class="dropdown-header portfolioCompanyLinksh6">
        <span>Quick Shortcut </span><br> User Applications & Reports
      </h6>
      <div class="links-float-left-main">
        <div *ngIf="enableGrillsDataFeature">
          <div class="links-float-left">
            <a (click)="onClickGrillsData()" class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:">

              <div class="col-md-4-custom">Grills Data</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="!portfolioCompanyLinksService.IPOutOfRange">
          <div *ngFor="let link of portfolioCompanyLinksService.Links" class="links-float-left">
            <a target="_blank" class="dropdown-item" href="{{ link.url }}">
              <div *ngIf="link.portfolioCompanyLinkName.svgIcon !=null" [innerHtml]="link.portfolioCompanyLinkName.svgIcon | safePipe: 'html'"></div> 
              <div class="col-md-4-custom">{{ link.linkName }}</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div >
          <div class="links-float-left">
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="openLink(url)" href="JavaScript:Void(0)" style="cursor: pointer">

              <div class="col-md-4-custom">Share via Email</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

So the dynamic items I am already sorting but how do I sort the static and dynamic items together?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a pipe to sort the array of objects base of property name like this

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(sortArray: any[], property:string ,method :'asc' | 'desc' = 'asc' ): any {
    const result  = [...sortArray]; // clone the array

    if (method === 'asc') { 
    return result.sort((a,b) => a[property] > b[property] ? 1 : -1);
    } else {
    return result.sort((a,b) => a[property] < b[property] ? 1 : -1);

    }
  }
}
```

*template*

```html
<div *ngFor="let link of portfolioCompanyLinksService.Links | sort :'linkName'"
   class="links-float-left">
....
</div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m74uyq)

Comment: This i did but i have some static values as you can see on my html file. How do i sort that?

Comment: what do you mean by static value ??

Comment: As you can see in the code there is grill data which is just a static value 
 <div class="links-float-left-main">
        <div *ngIf="enableGrillsDataFeature">
          <div class="links-float-left">
            <a (click)="onClickGrillsData()" class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:">

              <div class="col-md-4-custom">Grills Data</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment:  sorry I don't have an idea about that I asume just just have a menus base of the ngFor items

Comment: you may need to add more code or just create a demo base of your menu at stackblitz.com this will be helpful tome and other to undestand the structure and give a feedback